# Leaflet geojson merge attributes

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I need to merge the attributes on a leaflet geojson layer and another geojson based on a common field.  I have tried the following code, which does put the keys in the layer but all values are undefined.  How do I also get the value to transfer to the layer.  geojson is the variable that holds the attributes that I want merged in the layer.

```
var schemaL = new L.GeoJSON(schema);

// get RG attributes
schemaL.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  for (var i = 0; i < geojson.features.length; i++) {
    if (layer.feature.properties.CodeLink === geojson.features[i].properties.SiteId) {
      for (var key in geojson.features[i].properties) {
        layer.feature.properties[key] = geojson[key];
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. played around a bit and found the solution.  The geojson[key] statement gets the key only.  I had to add the following line add the end to the code to get and transfer the value.

```
  layer.feature.properties[key] = geojson.features[i].properties[key];
```